# How to get value of fields with same "Title" attribute Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

```
<%:Html.TextBox("NumTotal1, 0, new { id =1 , title="test"})%> 
<%:Html.TextBox("NumTotal2, 0, new { id =2 , title="test"})%> 
<%:Html.TextBox("NumTotal3, 0, new { id =3 , title="test"})%>
```

I want to sum value of texbox with title="test" attribute using JQUERY?
How can I? Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) (`[attr=val]`) to get your textboxes, then use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through and get your total, like this:

```
var total = 0;
$("input[title=test]").each(function() { 
  total += +this.value;
});
alert(total);
```

But these are fairly expensive compared to other selectors, so with a large number of elements I recommend giving your inputs a common class, making them less expensive to find.